# How to clear a variable of type ItemScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tell me please. I have a variable `public ItemScriptableObject elementItem;`. There is a function that fills it. But how to clear it from the function? Currently throwing an error: `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'ItemScriptableObject'`

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TestRay : MonoBehaviour {

    public ItemScriptableObject elementItem;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<Item>() != null) 
        {
            elementItem = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Item>().item;
            print(elementItem);
        }
        else {
            elementItem = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean set it to null?

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, clean up. Not 0 not null don't help.

Comment: You could remove the item from the game object?

Comment: `elementItem = null;`

Answer (score 0):

As said in message, the ItemScriptableObject cant be string (0, or other variable type) because its an "ItemScriptableObject" format, so you need to try to set it to be another "ItemScriptableObject". Supposing it is derived form a scriptableobject, you can give a look on the functions in the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html. I dont understand what you are really trying to do whit this variable.